# Question Tag moved forward in sentence

Tags: questions, question-mark, question-tags, indirect-question

If a question tag were moved forward in a sentence, how would it be punctuated? And if the question tag were a parenthetical,   would the sentence still be a question?

1. There’s no point, is there, in our leaving the house today?
2. There’s no point, is there, in our leaving the house today.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: (1) I'm not sure the concept of a parenthetical works in your examples, as the question tag makes a not insignificant change to the sense of the whole (it's not just a matter of the matrix being grammatical). (2) You can't argue that a polite request is involved here (contrast "Could you shut the window please, Tim.") so the interrogative form mandates a question mark. I assume you're thinking of two scenarios: a genuine question, and a rhetorical one. Both are acceptable, but both require the question mark according to all I've read. You'd need a speech tag (eg _asserted Jo_) to disambiguate.

Comment: *Under/Above the Water* (Tanith Lee, 2010): [*But it's no good, **is it,** to go on loving somebody dead?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22But+it%27s+no+good%2C+is+it%2C+to%22) The "tag question" is effectively an optional / parenthetical element, and they're normally set off by commas

Comment: So it’s not really a parenthetical, even though it’s set off by commas?

Comment: I don't see why people are dumping on this question. To me it's perfectly valid. And we've all seen, haven't we, instances of question tags moved forward in a sentence? Whether we've noticed them or not?